# Replace string in multiple files at once

Tags: command-line

I have a folder with several python scripts and I need to replace a path that is used in them to another path. The path is something like /projects/old/ and has to be changed into /new_partition/projects/

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the string in scripts using [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed).

- If all scripts are in a folder, you can run `sed` with `*` [wildcard](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm)

  ```
  sed -i 's|/projects/old/|/new_partition/projects/|g' *
  ```
- Or if you want to specify filenames

  ```
  sed -i 's|/projects/old/|/new_partition/projects/|g' filenames_separated_by_spaces
  ```
- If you want to manipulate all the `.py` scripts in the subdirectories of current directory, you can add [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)

  ```
  find . -name '*.py' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" 's|/projects/old/|/new_partition/projects/|g'
  ```

Comment: I tried it and it works after changing it to `sed -i '' '...' *`. How can I make it that also files in subfolders are changed?

Comment: @user1406177 I assume all scripts have py extension. Try `find . -name '*.py' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" 's|/projects/old/|/new_partition/projects/|g'`